# datatable is not working and need to filter the table using radio button date time year in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

dataTable is not working and need to filter the table using date month year.
This is the admin panel i,m working on ..i need to sort the table (every column) and by using some radio button need to filter the table

```
<ol class="formset">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 bg">
            <div class="stylehead">

                <input type="radio" name="client" value="client" class="client1" >Client <br>
                <input type="radio" name="client" value="manager" class="client1" checked> Manager
            </div>

            <div class="stylemid">
                <%= radio_button_tag 'filter','year'%> Year Till Date<br>
                <input type="radio" name="filter" value="date" class="client2"> Date wise

            </div>
            <div class="stylemid">
                <input type="radio" name="filter" value="today" class="client2" checked> Today<br>
                <input type="radio" name="filter" value="month" class="client2"> Month Till Date
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    </ol>
    <ol id="parent1" class="formset">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
            <table class="table text-center table-fill table-hover" id="example">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Manager</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Requirements</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Submissions</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Interview</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Selections</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Offers</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Onboarding</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="table-hover">
                <%yy=0%>
                <%cc=0%>
                <%qq=0%>



                <%@manager.each do |manager|%>
                    <%@s=ClientRecruiter.select("client_id").where("recruiter_id = ?",manager.id)
                    y=0
                    c=0
                    q=0

                    @s.each do |s|
                        y=y+JobPosting.where("client_id =?", s.client_id).count

                        @zz=JobPosting.select("id").where("client_id =?", s.client_id)
                        @zz.each do |zz|
                            c=c+AppliedJob.where("job_posting_id =?", zz.id).count

                            q=q+OfferLetter.where("client_id =? AND job_posting_id=?", s.client_id,zz.id).count
                        end
                    end%>
                    <%yy=yy+y%>
                    <%cc=cc+c%>
                    <%qq=qq+q%>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%="#{manager.first_name}  #{manager.last_name}" %></td>
                        <td> <%=y%></td>

                        <td> <%=c%></td>
                        <td> Null</td>                          
                        <td> Null</td>

                        <td><%=q%></td>
                        <td> Null</td>

                    </tr>
                <%end%>

                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Total</th>
                        <th class="text-center"><%=yy%></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><%=cc%></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Null</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Null</th>
                        <th class="text-center"><%=qq%></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Null</th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </ol>
```

this is the view page .
And this is the java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#parent2").css("display","none");
        $(".client1").change(function(){
        if ($('input[name=client]:checked').val() == "manager" ) {
            $("#parent1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
            $("#parent2").slideUp("fast");
        } else if ($('input[name=client]:checked').val() == "client" ) {
            $("#parent2").slideDown("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
            $("#parent1").slideUp("fast");
        }
     });
});
 $('#products').dataTable()
</script>
```

can any one help me out. Please help me with code. Where i,m doing wrong???

Comment: Can you provide logs/errors you got?

Comment: please provide the js fiddle link ?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't really tell whats going on from your question (my knowledge with dataTables isn't good) but the below railscast should give you a good reference and may be you can figure out what exactly is going wrong.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables